# Colorir palavra "até" um limitador

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso colorir no RichTextBox preenchido com varias linhas, um texto antes de um limitador, Observe por exemplo os destaques:

1- não pintar porque não tem limite

2- **pintar pois tem limite**: não pintar

3- não pintar porque não tem limite

4- **pintar pois tem limite**: não pintar

(...) *etc*

Perceba acima que o limitador é `:`, a palavra vai ficar com cor **até onde** esse limitador está. Depois desse limitador o texto vai ficar como está mesmo.

Preciso fazer isso enquanto a pessoa digita mais especificamente no evento **TextChanged do RichTextBox** e quando o FORM inicia. Se a pessoa apagou o limitador, todo o texto que estava em **tal linha** vai ficar com **uma cor só**. Agora se a pessoa "**colocou**" o limitador de volta, a palavra "**antes** "desse limitador vai ficar com cor novamente.

Descobri que a classe REGEX é um boa auxiliar para isso, no entanto, não tenho ideia de como usa-la sabiamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quer, aqui está:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int current = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    for(int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = richTextBox1.Lines[i];

        int index = line.IndexOf(':'), lineFirstIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(lineFirstIndex, index);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(lineFirstIndex, line.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Empty;
        }
    }
    richTextBox1.Select(current, 0);
}
```

Comment: Isso! é mais ou menos assim, só que quando vc vai inserindo muitas linhas no Rich com um limitador, só a primeira fica vermelha, tem que servir para todas as linhas "individualmente". Tem como fazer assim?

Comment: Tem, vou arrumar, no caso, cada linha tem um delimitador né?

Comment: Prontinho, editei.

Comment: Exatamente, cada linha tem seu delimitador. +1