# Mudar cor de expressões que começam com '@'

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu preciso criar um winform para mudar a cor de expressões que começem com '@'.

Por exemplo:

*nada @expressao nadamais*

O *@expressao* precisa ficar de outra cor.

O texto vai vir do input de uma textbox que o usuário digitar(pode ser uma richTextBox ou algo do Infragistics, tanto faz, desde que funcione).

Eu ja tentei separar a string da textbox com split e detectar quais delas começam com o @. Mas depois disso, não conseguia colorir as letras e mandar de volta para a textbox.

Também tentei algo com o selectionColor da richTextBox, porém a seleção apagava o @ e o cursor ia para a esquerda do caractere inserido, além de eu não conseguir "parar" a seleção quando queria.

Estou dando uma olhada em Regex para ver se consigo aplicar no meu problema.

Eu estou usando C# no Visual Studio Community 2017.

**EDIT**

Alterei o código que está nos comentários para tentar fazer funcionar no meu caso, mas o limitador não funciona. Acredito que isso ocorra porque a seleção começa só a partir de um '@', mas pode haver um ' ' antes, daí buga.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int current = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string line = richTextBox1.Lines[i];

            int index = line.IndexOf(' '), lineFirstIndex = line.IndexOf('@');

            if (index != -1 && lineFirstIndex != -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(lineFirstIndex, index);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                lineFirstIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);

                richTextBox1.Select(lineFirstIndex, line.Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Empty;

            }
        }
        richTextBox1.Select(current, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Por curiosidade: você perguntou isso no SOen também, né?

Comment: Perguntei kkkkk

Comment: Ah, bom. Eu tava com ela aberta pra deixar um comentário, mas aqui é melhor ainda. Enfim, você precisa nos dar um pouco mais de detalhes e mostrar o que já tentou.

Comment: Vou editar no post então. É a primeira vez que to postando aqui kk

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268162/colorir-palavra-at%C3%A9-um-limitador

Comment: botei o codigo no edit

Answer (score 0):

Consegui mudar  o background das expressões. Porém, se eu tenho um texto como

*"@expression xxxxxx"*, somente o @expression tem o background alterado. Até o momento que eu apago os X e o espaço, então tudo que eu escrevo a partir daí tem a cor do background alterada também.

Não sei se isso é alguma propriedade do SelectionBackColor, pois se eu mudo para SelectionColor, mudando a cor da fonte, esse problema não acontece.

Segue o código:

```
 private void FindAt() //acha arrobas
    {
        for(int r = 0; r <= tam; r++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < (tam - r); z++)
            {
                if (z > 8) break;

                String temp = text.Substring(r, z);
                char aux = '\0';

                if (lista.FindStringExact(temp) != -1)
                {
                    if (tam > r + z) aux = text.ElementAt(r + z);
                    if ((r > 0 && text.ElementAt(r - 1) == '@') && aux == ' ')
                    {
                        atIndex[0, ctrlAt] = r-1;   //salva posição inicial da variavel, incluindo o @ (por isso o -1)
                        atIndex[1, ctrlAt] = z + 1;   //salva comprimento da variavel, + 1 por causa do @ (segundo argumento da substring)
                        ctrlAt++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

E o código que troca a cor:

```
private void ColorAt() //colore variaveis
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < ctrlAt; a++)
        {
            if (atIndex[0, a] != -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(atIndex[0, a], atIndex[1, a]);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
        }
    }
```